# How to call a non-parameterised QML function from C++

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I am trying to call a function in my QML:

```
function resetSomething() {
    tempVar= undefined
}
```

I am not sure how to write the invokeMethod for this function.
I tried using something like that:

```
QQuickItem* qObj= findChild<QQuickItem>("temp");
if (qObj)
{
    QVariant returnArg;
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qObj, "resetSomething",Q_RETURN_ARG,QVariant,returnArg));
}
```

But it gives the error

> no matching function resetSomething(QVariant) found.

Comment: What is `temp` here? Does the function relates to this object? Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: Seems you lost '(' symbol after Q_RETURN_ARG. Try to call function in next way: `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qObj, "resetSomething", Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnArg) );`

Comment: `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qObj, "resetSomething", Qt::QueuedConnection);` should suffice. I've removed my previous comment on a whim but it was indeed correct. When you don't care about result and don't have parameter it seems to me that's the shortest way.

Comment: Thanku!! This worked, QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qObj, "resetSomething",Qt::QueuedConnection);

Comment: Also consider not doing this at all. Calling a function on the QML side creates a dependency from C++ to QML, restricting your flexibility on the QML side.

Depending on what you actual goal is there might be way better alternatives of doing it

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your error message Qt's Meta Object System is trying to find method resetSomething(**QVariant**), but your method doesn't have any parameters. I guess it's because of wrong **Q_RETURN_ARG** macro usage.
Seems that you can simply fix it like this:

```
QVariant returnArg;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qObj, "resetSomething", Qt::DirectConnection,
                          Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnArg));
```

Also I suggest you to read official [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod), it is brilliant.

BTW: [Nice repo](https://github.com/google/VoltAir) from Google with a lot of C++/JavaScript intercommunication. You can find a lot of useful patterns there.